# Is there any other way than using lazify to update contract if i find any issue later?

Tags: smartpy

How can we update a SmartPy contract. One way is through lazify but is there any other way to to so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call lambdas saved in the storage and write entrypoints that update those lambda.

If your lambdas deal with the storage it will rapidly be difficult to write them, lazy entrypoints simplifies management of storage and types of you.